# ASN1 empty OctetString

Tags: asn.1

I encode the data ( esim profile )" {
createFCP : {
fileDescriptor '4121'H,
fileID '6fc4'H,
lcsi '05'H,
securityAttributesReferenced '03'H,
efFileSize '64'H,
shortEFID ''H
}
" but shortEFID ''H I don't know how to do even I use BouncyCastle or jasn1 because shortEFID ''H has length zero without value.

Answer (score 1):

With ASN1, an empty OCTET STRING value is perfectly possible

If you encode it in a Tag/Length/Value (like BER, DER, etc...) the length value will be 0 and no value will be encoded.

So It is more a tooling question

I don't know BouncyCastle, but as it is Java, I would guess that an OCTET STRING is mapped to byte[] and an empty OCTET STRING would be mapped to null

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I raised a question to bean1 forum https://github.com/beanit/asn1bean/issues/45 and got the answer.  with java byte[] emptyArray = new byte[0];